# Вывод объекта в консоль

Tags: java, объекты, print

```
class BoxPrinter<T> {
    private T val;

    public BoxPrinter(T arg) {
        val = arg;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "{" + val + "}";
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return val;
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoxPrinter<Integer> value1 = new BoxPrinter<Integer>(new Integer(10));
        //////////тут///
        System.out.println(value1);
        ////////////////
        Integer intValue1 = value1.getValue();
        BoxPrinter<String> value2 = new BoxPrinter<String>("Hello world");
        ///////////и тут////
        System.out.println(value2);
        ///////////////////

    }
}
```

В код особо не вдавайтесь скопипастил с сайта. Почему помеченные строки `println` не выводят, как обычно, при попытке напечатать в консоль объект, что то вроде `BoxPrinter@1540e19d`, а печатают `10` и `Hello World`?

Comment: Пометь ovveride чтобы точно убедиться что метод ты верно написал . Может

Comment: Потому что в `BoxPrinter` переопределен метод `toString()`

Comment: @Санаев _Val это обжект поэтому выводит адрес_ какой еще адрес?

Comment: @Санаев интересный у Вас комментарий. Объекта `Val` у автора я не вижу и что за адрес выводиться тоже не могу понять. 10 чтоли? Это адрес? Или может быть "Hello World"?

Comment: Он про этот BoxPrinter@1540e19d

Comment: Только он у меня не в данном конкретном случае выводится а вообще при попытке передать объект в print()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строка

`System.out.println(value1);`

эквивалентна следующей

`System.out.println(value1.toString());`

то есть будет вызван метод `toString()` (он определен в классе `Object`). В Вашем классе `BoxPrinter` этот метод переопределен:

```
public String toString() {
    return "{" + val + "}";
}
```

Из-за этого в консоле Вы получаете 10 и "Hello World" вместо стандартного BoxPrinter@1540e19d.

Answer (score 3):

Компилятор сделает эту строку:

```
System.out.println(value1);
```

В эту:

```
System.out.println(value1.toString());
```

Если метод toString() не определен то будет использоваться метод из класса Object, который определяется так:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Это обозначает, что сначала будет выведено расположение класса, собачка и хэш-код объекта.

Comment: Вы думаете, если дать второй идентичный ответ, то автор лучше поймет в чем проблема?

Comment: @notaProgrammer, ну, в этом ответе написано, например, как выглядит `toString`, чего нет в другом ответе)

Comment: Здесь я объясняю, что будет когда не объявляется метод toString() используется вариант из Object. И потом к примеру: сказать при делении дробей одна дробь переворачивается и не сказав до этого, что 2+2 равно 4? Это довольно глупо. Это можно назвать основу ответа, на которой строится дальнейший ответ.

Comment: @АлександрКудрявцев во-первых, не объявляется, а переопределяется. А во-вторых, я написал _вместо стандартного BoxPrinter@1540e19d_.

Comment: С первым соглашусь. А вы объяснили, что обозначает BoxPrinter@1540e19d, как метод toString() определяется в классе Object и  когда он употребляется.