# com.company.Przyklad03@22d8cfe0 при чтении обьекта из файла.ser - Java

Tags: java

я пытаюсь записать обьект в файл.ser, и у меня вроде это получилось, но когда я
хочу считать этот файл и вывести это в консоли то получаю это **com.company.Przyklad03@22d8cfe0**
Вот мой код
Запись обьекта:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Przyklad03 implements Serializable {
    private String test;

    private void setTest(String s) {
        test = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Przyklad03 przyklad03 = new Przyklad03();
        przyklad03.setTest("Ta tresc bedzie zapisana w pliku...");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("przyklad03.ser"));
            o.writeObject(przyklad03);
            o.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Чтение обьекта:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Przyklad04 implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("przyklad03.ser"));
            Przyklad03 obj = (Przyklad03) o.readObject();
            o.close();
            System.out.print(obj);
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Метод toString переопредилиди для Przyklad03 ?

Comment: Ничего не делал

Comment: Вам нужно переопределить метод toString(), чтобы при выводе в консоль он автоматически вызывался или вывести`obj.getText()`, соответственно, создав метод getText(), который возвращает строку

Comment: А как так сделать?

Comment: Можете автоматически сгенерировать в ide метод toString для Przyklad03 или вручную

Comment: А можете сделать пример решения в ответе к вопросу, а то я не очень понимаю

Comment: я уже почти ответил на ваш сегодняшний вопрос про "базы данных ...". Зачем удалили вопрос?

Comment: @nikoshi я уже сам нашел в чем была проблема)

Comment: @nikoshi вместо этого я опять задал вопрос по чтению обьектов из файла, у меня там опять проблемы

Comment: вы же вчера здесь об этом уже узнали) надо внимательнее быть) и если я помог вчера, то примите мой ответ

Comment: @да, я просто уже еще лучше разобрался, но именно ваш вопрос и помог мне, спасибо) можете так же заглянуть на мой новый вопрос)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128083/discussion-between-nikoshi-and-kaban-of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package com.company;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Przyklad03 implements Serializable {
    private String test;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return test;
    }

    private void setTest(String s) {
        test = s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Przyklad03 przyklad03 = new Przyklad03();
        przyklad03.setTest("Ta tresc bedzie zapisana w pliku...");
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("przyklad03.ser"));
            o.writeObject(przyklad03);
            o.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839996/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C) описана похожая ситуация

В вашем случае программа отработала корректно.
Если вы хотите, чтобы при вызове `System.out.print(obj);` выводилась какая-то информация, вам необходимо в классе `Przyklad03` создать метод

```
public String toString() {
    return test; 
    // Или что угодно вместо:
    // return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Можно сделать иначе, например так:

```
System.out.print(obj.getText());
```

Тогда вам нужно создать метод

```
public String getText() {
    return test; 
}
```

Суть в том, что при `System.out.print(obj);` компилятор автоматически вызывает `System.out.print(obj.toString());`, поэтому более элегантно было бы переопределить этот метод.

> Но почему **переопределить**, я же ни от кого не наследовался?

На самом деле все классы в Java наследуются от класса `Object`, где реализован `toString()`

Однако можно и просто создать отдельную функцию, например `getText()`